# Avoid component flickering on redirect Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

i have an app created with angular 6, i manage the logged statement with a guard, but when the user is logged and he goes to /login it must redirect to /dashboard, it redirects, but the login component appears for a moment and then redirects

Any way to avoid that flickering?

Comment: Probably, having your code would certainly help telling you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.router.navigate(['/home']);` in your component when login.